# Where to store MAC OS application specific data (Accessible only by the application and not the user) ?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am working on a MAC application. Is there a provision to store data generated by the app (be it an image or any other document) at a location accessible only by the application. I read through the sandbox feature, but the container created is still accessible by the user directly. Since I am from an iOS background, wondering if the feature to store application data in iOS devices  , not accessible by the user directly, is available in Mac applications too? Please advice.

Comment: The sandbox is the best you can do. By design anything created by a user is modifyible by that user You could create a new user and through IPC get your app to talk to a daemon running as that user but a admin user could still access the data.

Comment: You can use the library directory for this, it the same as on iOS, the user will be able to access it. Even on iOS users can easily access the document and library directory on there device. In OSX the library directory is hidden from the user by default.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. So, like our iOS applications and devices, the feature to store data not accessible to any other user or application isn't provided for Mac apps. Is it so?

Comment: You can't save files locally that your user can't access, but you can encrypt the files if you want to. If encryption isn't enough you can save the data in a remote database (you will need some kind of remote server with a database)

Comment: @rckoenes- but the library directory is not accessible on the device right. It is only when I run the iOS app on my Mac machine, it allows me to explore these locations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a provision to store data generated by the app (be it an
>   image or any other document) at a location accessible only by the
>   application.

**No.** An administrative user can access any file on the machine. I can think of three options:

- **Rethink the requirement**. The user should be in charge of the application, not the other way around. An application that needs to hide user data from the user sounds suspicious.
- **Store the data on a server** that the user can only access through your application.
- **Encrypt the data** so that the user will have a hard time using it.

By the way, data is only hidden from the user on iOS because the entire file system is hidden. The permission system is about the same as on OS X.

Comment: Exactly! The safest would be external storage, but one should wonder if it is really needed.

Comment: @Raj you can accept the answer if it solves your problem by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Totally correct, but worth noting that storing the data on a server or "encrypting" the data cannot actually secure them from an authorized user either. (I say "encrypt" because it's not encryption if there is no secret; and there is nowhere to hide the secret.) The best you can do here is slow down someone who is not highly motivated to find the information. That often is fine and more than enough, but just don't spend too much time and money developing it since it will not really solve anything.

Comment: @RobNapier Agree, but a quibble: encryption is encryption no matter how well (or poorly) you hide the key.

Comment: I completely disagree. "Encryption" without a secret is shuffling. Shuffling is a valid thing to do (see ROT-13), but it is not encryption. AES with a hard-coded key is just a very fancy form of ROT-13. This is not a matter of "hiding" the key. The program that includes the algorithm also includes the key. Saying otherwise is like saying ROT-13 is "encryption" if you didn't tell the user "it's ROT-13" but it's all in the program.

Comment: BTW, I would agree that ROT-13 *is* encryption if the "13" part of it were actually kept a secret (not shipped as part of the program and must be entered by the user). It's terrible encryption, but there is a secret.